# Is it possible to set which photo is shown as the Lighroom folder preview?

Tags: lightroom

When you mouse over folders in the `Library` module of Lighroom, the image shown in the `Navigator` is always just the first file in that folder.

Is there a way to set a specific photo to be this preview image?

Comment: Is it still the same file if you re-sort the images?

Comment: @Alex.S Changing the order works, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the only way to change the preview image is to reorder the images in the folder so that the desired image is first.